# React:How to submit data to a modal?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a job list. In this job list, we have a button to open modal for enter the detail of a job. However, when I pass a default job object with default value to the modal, the modal cannot show the default job value.

Because some default attributes are came from remote API, so in the JobList component, I use the useEffect hook to retrieve data from remote API.

Would you tell me what's going on?

My code is resided [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axajos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and there is a logical error.

You need to add `break;` after addJob case statement in JobList.js.

Because of that, defaultJobObj is reiniting as undefined object.

-- ADDITION --

You need to handle `defaultJobObj` prop update in JobForm component.

You can define a hook and reinit `items` in reducer.

```
let reducer = (state, action) => {
    let result = { ...state };
    switch (action.type) {
      case "reinit":
        result.job = defaultJobObj;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return result;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateItems({
      "type":"reinit"           
    })
  }, [defaultJobObj])
```

Comment: Thank you for help, unfortunately, after I added the `break` it still does not work.

Comment: And in init case statement, you need to use result.defaultJobObj. You are using different name of object now. In the future, do not use similar names for temporary values. Instead add some prefix. :)

Comment: You need one more fix. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use state management like Redux/React Context to pass the values to your modal